# Upload File to Market Error

Tags: android

Uploaded first file last night - successfully : BUT made a mistake with the KeyStore so was not able to do any updates. Long story short, I ended up with 2 versions on Market (different names) which I have 'unpublished'.  Problem with Keystore was due to my spelling

Anyway, now all is sorted out and I want to upload a new file, with corrections etc BUT when I try to upload I get an error window headed 'Message from webpage' and the content is:

> Unable to process the uploaded file.  Please check if it exceeds the size limit

The file size is 4204 kB

Anyone know what the size limit is?

I used the integrated Eclipe to generate the .apk file so it has been compressed etc.

Maybe there is a total limit of files/sizes uploaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried to email for help and looked in the "known issues" section.  This has already been reported.  I found the following:

We're aware that some developers may encounter one or both of the following error messages when attempting to upload an app: 1) "Unable to parse response. If you have a browser extension or add-on installed which changes the JSON response, please disable and refresh this page." 2) "Unable to process the uploaded file. Please check if it exceeds the size limit." We're aware of this issue and are currently working to resolve it.

So they are working on it.

Comment: If I find anything further out. I will let you know.

Comment: Much appreciate that feedback.  I searched the KPF but must have missed it - Oh to have young bright eyes again :-)

Comment: DOH!  I rebooted my machine and it let me upload the apk after that.  If I hear anything about how to delete apps (rather than just unpublish) I will note it here.

Comment: It uploaded this morning. Got an e-mail from teh Android MArket guys and they said that there was a problem which they resolved. So all's well that ends well.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, this also happens if your Android Market registration is still in the approval stage.

I get this after successfully uploading an apk, but when trying to upload other assets ie: screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

There is a limit to app sizes, but you're nowhere near it. Something else is wrong. We've found that the market is sometimes slow to propagate changes we make to all parts of the app management system. Perhaps something like that is going on with your app—the system may not have had time to clear out the record of the old app from everywhere in the system. If the problem persists, I suggest completely deleting your app from the market and starting fresh with a new package name.

Comment: I thought it was not possible to delete old apps.

Comment: The app I am uploading now has a different name, different package name etc., so Market should be seeing it as a totally new application.  Still, I would like to delete the old one(s) if you have any details on how to do it.  All I could find was UnPublish

Answer (score 1):

*Anyone know what the size limit is?*

Yes. it's 50Mb currently.
From: https://market.android.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113469

> APK file size: Maximum supported size
>   is 50MB.

Comment: Ah well, so size is not the problem :-(